# At wich $n$ reaches the sequence its target value?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There are three parameters:

1. $y_s=y[0]$ start value
2. $y_t=y[n]$ target value
3. $\alpha, 0>\alpha\leq1$ smoothness

Starting at $y[0]=y_s$ the sequence is developed with this recursive formula:

$y[i]=\alpha\cdot y[i-1]+(1-\alpha)\cdot y_t$ for $i>0$

It can be transformed to a non-recursive form:

$y[i]=\alpha^i\cdot y_s+(1-\alpha^i)\cdot y_t$

At some $n$, this sequence reaches the target value $y_t$, i. e. $y[n]=y_t$.
**Edit:** This is my observation, but I can't proof this.

**My question is: How can I calculate the number of time steps $n$?**

I've tried this:

- $\alpha^n\cdot y_s+(1-\alpha^n)\cdot y_t=y_t$
- $\alpha^n\cdot y_s+y_t-\alpha^n\cdot y_t=y_t$
- $\alpha^n\cdot y_s-\alpha^n\cdot y_t=0$

For the last one, the solution is $y_s=y_t$ but this can't be right.

Here is an example sequence with $y_s=10,y_t=100,\alpha=0.7$:
[image: example sequence]

Comment: "At some $n$, this series reaches the target value" - are you sure of this? Also, minor note, but it would be more correct to use 'sequence' than 'series' here.

Comment: The last equality implies $y_t =y_s$ as $\alpha \neq 0$. This is right, as you never reach $y_t$, you only can get arbitrary close to it, as $\alpha^n(y_s-y_t)$ can be arbitrary small, but not $0$ for finite $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y[i]=\alpha\cdot y[i-1]+(1-\alpha)\cdot y_t$, then $y[i]-y_t=\alpha(y[i-1]-y_t)$. This tells us that the distance between $y[i]$ and $y_t$ decays geometrically, and will only be exactly $0$ if $y_s=y_t$, i.e. if it starts at the target.

If, on the other hand, you want $y[i]$ to merely be *close* to $y_t$ (e.g. within $\varepsilon$ of $y_t$), we can see that $y[i]-y_t=\alpha^i(y_s-y_t)$, so:

$$\vert y[i]-y_t \vert \le \varepsilon \iff \alpha^i\vert y_s-y_t \vert \le \varepsilon\iff i\ge \log_{\alpha^{-1}}\left(\frac{\vert y_s-y_t \vert}{\varepsilon}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$r_i = y_t - y_i$$
be the distance between the $i$-th term of your sequence and its 'destination'.

Then
$$\begin{align}
r_{i+1} &= y_t - y_{i+1} \\
 & = y_t - \alpha\cdot y_i - (1-\alpha)\cdot y_t \\
 & =\alpha\cdot y_t - \alpha \cdot y_i \\
 & =\alpha\cdot (y_t - y_i) \\
 & =\alpha\cdot r_i
\end{align}$$
is a geometric sequence with ratio $\alpha$. It will approach $0$ infinitely for $|\alpha|<1$, but will never reach it, so the $y$ sequence will **never** reach $y_t$, alhough it will approach it arbitrarily close, if you wait long enough.

The above holds, of course, unless $r$ sequence starts from zero; in that case $y_s = y_t$ and the whole $y$ sequence is already in a 'target'.